# What generates notification for the naturalSize of a video in MPMoviePlayer?

Tags: ios

I have  a video in one tab  and some  data analysis based on the video in another tab.
My second  tab depends a lot on the naturalSize of the video.
I listen to the notification for the video's naturalSize in my first tab and as soon as I get it I store the naturalSize in a shared object for both the tabs and in viewWillAppear of the second tab I use the that value.

My problem is the notification for naturalSize is not generated unless I play the video.
How should I go about it ?

I tried playing and pausing the vidoe in first tab's viewDidLoad but it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:** Although There is no direct solution for generating the notification but please checkout my answer for a workaround where you don't need to be dependent on the notification at all when you are not streaming a remote video and it's locally available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design and there is no workaround. The natural size of a video when being played back using `MPMoviePlayerController` is not known until that movie is playable - that is, the player needs to pre buffer the video until enough information is available.

Answer (score 0):

Although as Till correctly points it out that there is no work around for this problem,
I found a solution that worked for me.

naturalSize may not be available before we start playing the video but If you have the file locally and you have its URL,

One can use AVFoundation framework's AVAsset class.

It has a class method assetWithURL that creates and returns an AVAsset object.
`AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithUrl:..];`

It has a naturalSize property.

`CGSize size = asset.naturalSize`

although this method is only available to iOS 5, we can do a respondsToSelector and if it fails then use

`+ (AVURLAsset *)URLAssetWithURL:(NSURL *)URL options:(NSDictionary *)options`

AVURLAsset is a concrete subclass of AVAsset and can be used when the URL of the local video file is available.

Comment: When using this solution, you will actually download the very same data twice (at least a bigger part of it). So the AVAsset just as MPMoviePlayerController will download the first part of your content. But then again, if it works this way for you :D....

Comment: Ya but the I have the file and I dont need to download it. MPMoviePlayer is made so generic that even if I have the vidoe in my local disk it works in the same manner as if I am streaming a remote video.
and thats why I only get the naturalSize when the notification is generated and the notification wont be generated unless I play the video but In my case I need the naturalSize before the moviePlayer plays the video :)